# Not able to include sqlite3 in c program

Tags: c, sqlite3

I installed libsqlite3-dev from ubuntu software center and after the installation, i found the sqlite3.h file in usr/include folder. There was no error in including that header file, but i am not able to use the functions declared in it. It shows the error 'Undefined reference to sqlite_open' and same for all other functions declared in it.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the exact build command you are using and at least a few lines of the actual error message - it sounds like you are not linking the library

Comment: How am i suppose to do the linking process for this library ?

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite program and the library has not linked this might have caused the issue. In this case please try the below,

g++ mail.cpp -lsqlite3